# When I input a massive array I get ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2. >>>

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, svm

I'm trying apply a swm to imported arrays (they are extremely large). However I keep getting the following error in line 22:

> "ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2."

I have tried to convert the array to 2 dimensions but nothing seems to work.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use("ggplot")
from sklearn import svm

alap = np.loadtxt("next")
print(alap)
al = np.loadtxt("next2")
print(al)
x = [1, 5, 1.5, 8, 1, 9]
y = [2, 8, 1.8, 8, 0.6, 11]

X = np.array([[alap],
         [al]])
F = X.reshape(X.shape[0], -1)
w = [0,1]

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C = 1.0)
clf.fit(F,w)

print(clf.predict([F]))

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `F` has dimension two. `[F]`,  which is what you're passing to the `predict` calls, is effectively three-dimensional. Why do you enclose `F` in a list in the `predict` call?

Comment: Is there any alternative way to input data so we can make svm predictions or to convert the **predict** to 2d. When I try arrays such as [4,4], it seems to be fine.

Comment: @pfftkhaganate: Again: you're passing `[F]` in the predict call, which doesn't make any sense. Replace `clf.predict([F])` with `clf.predict(F)`.